# sshd bad configuration on server

Tags: ssh

Could someone help me. After changing the port of the server using this command `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I cant connect to the server using putty.
It says connection refused. Both `systemctl status ssd.service` and `journalctl -xe` encounter this error.

How could I restore or kill this error? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open your config file using `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Once the file opens, type `:set key=` in order to reset the encryption key to a blank value. Afterwards save your file with `:w` and exit vim using `:q`. Your config file should be plaintext afterwards.

As an explanation: it seems that the last time you edited the file with vim (when you changed the port), you typed `:X` in vim, which tells vim to encrypt the file when saving. You should have been prompted to specify a key, which was then saved to the option "key". The tipps above help to revert that.

Comment: If you choose to reinstall OpenVPN, please remember to purge the config files (e.g. `sudo apt-get remove --purge openvpn && sudo apt-get install openvpn`, if you use apt as your package manager).

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks a lot. That is really what I've doing during my configuration. God Bless.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you messed up your sshd.conf, possibly by using VimCrypt, and saving the file encrypted instead of as plain text. You could try to open it with vim, decrypt it and save it as plain text. As it is, the sshd process is unable to parse your sshd configuration.

Comment: how? what command should I use and process? I'm really new to this linux administration . thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to tell, since it's unclear how you managed to destroy your sshd.conf file. You could consider removing and reinstalling sshd so your package manager installs a default config.

Comment: what i did is I just change the port using vim then restart.

Comment: Based on the error message you're posting the entire sshd.conf file is bad, starting at the first line. Your best change is reinstalling ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I what to share what I've done to addressed the above error for the other to know, who are also experiencing this kind of situation.The situation was, the sshd was totally corrupted. execute the sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config and totally erased and encode again the sshd configuration. Note: do not enter a key for encryption, if it would prompt, just leave it blank.

Here is the sshd configuration:

[image]